# Exponential optimization problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, convexity

\begin{eqnarray}
\arg\max_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\exp\left(-{\frac{\left(X(i,j)-{U_k}(i,j)\right)^2}{2}}\right),\:\: k=0,\dots,p
\end{eqnarray}
where $X$ and $U_k$ are the $p\times p$ matrices, and $X(i,j)$ and $U_k(i,j)$ are the $(i,j)$-th elements of $X$ and $U_k$, respectively. The question is that can I simplify my maximization problem as the following?

\begin{eqnarray}
\arg\max_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\exp\left(-{\frac{\left(X(i,j)-{U_k}(i,j)\right)^2}{2}}\right)&& =\arg\:\max_{k}\:\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\exp\left(-{\frac{\left(X(i,j)-{U_k}(i,j)\right)^2}{2}}\right)\right)\nonumber\\
&&=\arg\max_{k}\:\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\ln\left(\exp\left(-{\frac{\left(X(i,j)-{U_k}(i,j)\right)^2}{2}}\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

or, is it true to simplify as the following?

\begin{eqnarray}
\arg\max_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\exp\left(-{\frac{\left(X(i,j)-{U_k}(i,j)\right)^2}{2}}\right)&& =\arg\:\max_{k}\:\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left(-{\frac{\left(X(i,j)-{U_k}(i,j)\right)^2}{2}}\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, not.

Indeed, suppose that $U_k=X$ for $k=2,\dots,p$. Suppose also that $U_k(i,j)=X(i,j)$ for $k=0,1$ if $(i,j)\notin\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$. Then the question becomes the following:

> Is it true that for all nonnegative real $a_0,b_0,a_1,b_1$
> $$\arg\max_{k\in\{0,1\}}\sum_{k=0}^1(e^{-a_k}+e^{-b_k})
> =\arg\max_{k\in\{0,1\}}\sum_{k=0}^1(-a_k-b_k)\text{?} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
> (here $a_k$ stands for $(X(0,0)-U_k(0,0))^2/2$ and $b_k$ stands for $(X(0,1)-U_k(0,1))^2/2$).

But this is not true if e.g. $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2)=\left\{\frac{178}{5},\frac{147}{10},0,\frac{537}{5}\right\}$. Indeed, then the left-hand side of \eqref{1} is $1$ and the right-hand side of \eqref{1} is $0$.

The same effect is attained if e.g. $a_1=0$, $a_0=b_0=c\to\infty$, and $b_1=2c+1$.